# Choppy audio decoding when using swr_convert in Android

Tags: android, c, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

I'm using the following C function to decode packets in Android (with JNI). When I play an mp3 file the code works fine however and wma file results in choppy audio. I suspect the issue may be with the "swr_convert" function and the data_size I'm using but I'm not sure. Does anyone know why this would be happening?

```
int decodeFrameFromPacket(AVPacket *aPacket) {
    int n;
    AVPacket *pkt = aPacket;
    AVFrame *decoded_frame = NULL;
    int got_frame = 0;

    if (aPacket->stream_index == global_audio_state->audio_stream) {

        if (!decoded_frame) {
            if (!(decoded_frame = avcodec_alloc_frame())) {
                __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, "Could not allocate audio frame\n");
                return -2;
            }
        }

        if (avcodec_decode_audio4(global_audio_state->audio_st->codec, decoded_frame, &got_frame, aPacket) < 0) {
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, "Error while decoding\n");
            return -2;
        }

        int data_size = 0;

        if (got_frame) {
            /* if a frame has been decoded, output it */
            data_size = av_samples_get_buffer_size(NULL, global_audio_state->audio_st->codec->channels,
                    decoded_frame->nb_samples,
                    global_audio_state->audio_st->codec->sample_fmt, 1);
        }

        swr_convert(global_audio_state->swr, (uint8_t **) &gAudioFrameRefBuffer, decoded_frame->nb_samples, (uint8_t const **) decoded_frame->data, decoded_frame->nb_samples); 

        avcodec_free_frame(&decoded_frame);

        gAudioFrameDataLengthRefBuffer[0] = data_size;
        return AUDIO_DATA_ID;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you initialize global_audio_state->swr ?

Comment: Yes I did. If I add print statements it appears avcodec_decode_audio4 is taking significantly longer for WMA files.

Comment: Are you trying to play the audio in the same thread you decode it? This is not a good idea, you need to do it in separate threads.

Comment: Hi @WilliamSeemann, could you please share the solution you found for the problem? I'm trying to decode AAC using the same.